# How to Use AND in Ruby Regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm having problems with Ruby regex.

How do you do AND(&) regex in ruby?

ex:

```
cat and dog
cat
dog

I just want to match "cat and dog"
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do something like a AND using positive look aheads

```
(?=.*cat)(?=.*dog).*
```

See it [here on Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/1xfzGhL8Ev) **Updated link!**

This positive lookahead `(?=.*cat)` checks if there is "cat" somewhere within the string, then the same is done for "dog" using `(?=.*dog)`. If those both assertions are true then the complete string is matched with the `.*` at the end.

The advantage is that it will also match

> dog and cat

and not only

> cat and dog

but it will also match

> dogs and cats

if you want exact matches, then use this

```
(?=.*\bcat\b)(?=.*\bdog\b).*
```

`\b` is a word boundary, i.e. it matches between a word and a non word character.

See it [here](http://www.rubular.com/r/uR1XOkTcrF)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear.

If you wish to match only those strings which contain *both* "cat" *and* "dog" (maybe as parts of a word), you could do:

```
/^.*(cat.*dog|dog.*cat).*$/
```

The above regex will match "concatenation dogma", but not "concatenation".

If you want to ensure that "cat" and "dog" appear as words by themselves, do:

```
/^.*(\bcat\b.*\bdog\b|\bdog\b.*\bcat\b).*$/
```

The above regex will match "cat and dog", but not "concatenation dogma" or "cat dogma".

Source: http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/intro.html#S5

Answer (score 0):

and is the default action in a regexp, i.e. first match this then followed by that and so on.

to match cat AND dog, use something like

```
cat.*dog
```

which means, match "cat" followed by anything AND then followed by "dog". But then again I might have misunderstood your question...

Answer (score 0):

It depends of what you want.

You can use wild card

```
cat.+dog
```

Or

```
cat.+dog|dog.+cat
```

Or

```
cat +and +dog
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no `and` operator in `Regexp`s, simply because it doesn't make sense. It will *never* match: how can a `String` both be `'cat'` *and* `'dog'` at the same time?

Comment: `schrodinger.pet.species.to_s`

Comment: Of course a string can be both a "cat" and "dog" at the same time – `"a cat and a dog are in the same string"`.