# How to give multiple strings to the Rspec stdout matcher?

Tags: ruby, rspec, stdout

I have some rspec tests to check the output of a command.

Previously, I was mocking the entire $stdout.string and I could do this:

```
  expect($stdout.string).to include 'DEBUG -- : Request Headers:'
  expect($stdout.string).to include 'Bearer foo'
  expect($stdout.string).to include 'Some other thing'
```

I'm refactoring this to switch to the rspec `output(arg).to_stdout` method.

However, [looking at the docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/output-matcher), it only seems to allow giving a string or a regex:

```
RSpec.describe "output.to_stdout matcher" do
  specify { expect { print('foo') }.to output.to_stdout }
  specify { expect { print('foo') }.to output('foo').to_stdout }
  specify { expect { print('foo') }.to output(/foo/).to_stdout }
```

I tried chaining expectations and it didn't work:

```
expect { print 'foo bar baz' }.to output(/foo/).to_stdout.and output(/bar/).to_stdout.and output(/baz/).to_stdout
```

Gives result:

```
 Failure/Error: expect { print 'foo bar baz' }.to output(/foo/).to_stdout.and output(/bar/).to_stdout.and output(/baz/).to_stdout

      expected block to output /bar/ to stdout, but output nothing

   ...and:

      expected block to output /baz/ to stdout, but output nothing
```

Is there a way to give an array of expected strings?

Comment: maybe you can use positive lookahead in the regex like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6437567/2981429)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The matcher passed to `output` can be any matcher, this lets you move your chained `.and` composition inside using the `match` matcher:

```rb
expect { print 'foo bar baz' }.to output( match(/foo/).and match(/bar/).and match(/baz/) ).to_stdout
```

Or closer to your original example `include` can take a list of strings:

```rb
expect { print 'foo bar baz' }.to output(include('foo', 'bar', 'baz')).to_stdout
```

Answer (score 3):

As you seem to have found out already, `output` doesn't allow you to chain or [compose](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/composing-matchers#composing-matchers-with-<code>output</code>), but you can capture the `expect` block and run multiple tests on it.

```
it 'verifies hello world' do
  expectation = expect { puts 'hello'; puts 'world' }
  expectation.to output(/hello/).to_stdout
  expectation.to output(/world/).to_stdout
end
```

Comment: It looks like this exercises the expectation twice?